# increase font size iteratively using javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, font-size

```
var text = document.querySelector('p')
for(var i=10px; i<=40px; i++)
  text.style.fontSize = i;
```

I want a script which increases the font size in every iteration of the for-loop. The above code is the prototype of my requirement (which won't work since pixels can't be assigned to a variable). Help me providing the correct code.

Comment: There is no `10px` literal.

Comment: Is the number of you p tags dynamically or fixed?

Comment: Just wonder if you have 1 p tag and want to increase only that one like an animation or if you want to have every p tag with higher font size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use setTimeout recursion instead, so the text doesn't increase in size instantly:

```js
var text = document.querySelector('p');

function increaseTextSize(size) {
  text.style.fontSize = size + 'px'; 
  if (size <= 40) setTimeout(increaseTextSize, 50, size + 1);
}
increaseTextSize(10);
```

```html
<p>my text</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try out this demo using CSS transition effect:

```js
// After 500ms change the font from 10 to 60px
// and css will take care of the rest
setTimeout(() => {
  var text = document.querySelector('p');
  text.style.fontSize = '60px';
  text.style.color = 'blue';  // <-- you can also add color effects, if you want
}, 500);
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: red;
  -webkit-transition: all 2.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 2.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 2.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 2.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var text = document.querySelector('p')

for (var i = 10; i <= 40; i++) {
  text.style.fontSize = `${i}px`;
}
```

You cannot append `px` in the loop since it has to be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = document.querySelector('p');

function increaseTextSize(size) {
  text.style.fontSize = size + 'px'; 
  if (size <= 40) setTimeout(increaseTextSize, 50, size + 1);
}
increaseTextSize(10);
```

```html
<p>my text</p>
```

Dfhg

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).